# How to use capistrano patch with svn?

Tags: php, svn, capistrano

I am trying to deploy my PHP application with capistrano. I am using svn repository and not able to work capistrano patch on it. Is it possible to use "cap patch FROM=v1.1 TO=v1.3" command for subversion as mentioned for git?

Please let me know the patch configuration to be done in deploy.rb for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can always create our own custom task for the same as well, although that will include proper implementation of rollback and updates.